# Enable "Hide extensions for known file types" with C++

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, cmd, operating-system

I want to know how to enable/disable the **Hide extensions for known file types** under windows 10 (Older versions should work aswell) in **C++.**

[How to enable it in Windows Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXDqK.png)

[How to enable it in File Explorer Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1sJc.png)

If it's not possible to do in c++ I would be okay with cmd/powershell aswell!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell

To **Enable** the option (i.e. to *hide* known extensions), use:

```
$regPath = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $regPath)) { $null = New-Item -Path $regPath -Force }
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $regPath -Name 'HideFileExt' -Value 1 -Type DWord -Force
```

To **Disable**  (i.e. to *show* known extensions) use:

```
$regPath = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $regPath)) { $null = New-Item -Path $regPath -Force }
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $regPath -Name 'HideFileExt' -Value 0 -Type DWord -Force
```

or remove the entry:

```
$regPath = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
Remove-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $regPath -Name 'HideFileExt' -Force
```

After changing this in the registry, you need to either **log off** or **stop the explorer process** with `Stop-Process -Name explorer` for the settings to take effect.

<sup>The above uses `HKCU`(HKEY_CURRENT_USER) but if you need to change this for all users, use `HKLM` instead</sup>